# Session failing with not a valid month error

Tags: oracle, informatica

I have a view in oracle database,so I need to pull that data into Amazon redshift,so I used IPC to pull data,but my session is keeps failing showing the error "ORA-01843: Not a valid month"..Im not doing any transformations just pulling data in view(oracle).

​2.in DB we have datatypes defined correctly as DATE and date columns are formatted as 'dd-mon-yy,but we are getting error when we run in informatica.

3.we are using SQL query in SQL qualifier.here we r just using select all columns from that view.
could you guys please help on this.

Comment: You are definitely trying to access a date column with string input. Is there any `some_col = 'date-like-value'`? For example `dttm = '12-APR-22'`? Use [datetime literals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1) for that: `dttm = date '2022-04-12'`

Comment: Yes exactly ,it date type datatype ,with 12-jan-2021' format..how to resolve this..but it is marked as date datatype in informatica also

Comment: you need to check how the column is defined in source. it seems Oracle view has some issue and view definition or SQL doesnt match to the datatype in DB. have you run the view in DB and tried to fetch all data ? can you post view definition?you should be able to resolve this using `to_date(dt,'dd-mon-yy')` and concert it to a date.

Comment: Yeah,i ran the query in oracle DB,there i got data,but whenever I run session in informatica ,I'm getting this error.What to do now?please help

Comment: @KoushikRoy I tried to_date in SQL query which is in SQL qualifier,then also I got same error.

Comment: If the column data type is actually DATE then it does not have a human-friendly format like '12-Jan-2021' - dates (and timestamps) are stored with an internal representation, and formatted as strings by applications and clients, often using your session NLS_DATE_FORMAT setting, which may be DD-Mon-YYYY. If it's really a DATE both ends then there should be no conversion, but from the error it is being treated as a string somewhere. Are you sure both the view and the underlying table really have it defined as DATE and not as a formatted string?

Comment: @AlexPoole in view it is date,and also date in underlying table where this view is defined

Comment: You need to find the statement that was executed in the database, then connect to the database and set some very odd date format (for example `alter session set nls_date_format = 'MON-yyyy-dd'`) and try to execute the same query (better to use CTAS). Maybe the issue is in the generated code or may it be due to the view's developer relied on the "default" and used some implicit conversion. Another possible reason: you encounter this error only when process entire dataset, but IDE generally fetches few rows of the cursor (50-500), which may not have corrupted data.

Comment: can you pls share view definition and infa session log ?