# Getting error while running session as not avalid month

Tags: oracle, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a oracle view in which we have column called dayofset which defined from subtraction of two date columns like(to_date(date_column1)-to_date(date_column2)) and it is stored as number(38) datatype.
2.so,when I run session in informatica to get data from oracle view to redshift.im getting error like "not a valid month".
3.Input values for that column is like (25-JAN-21,10-APR-13)
4.im getting the output values like 1,2,3,4... Like this all are integer values.(this column just do the datediff operation) and provide the difference between two dates.

Could you guys please help on this.

Comment: It's hard to comment without seeing the values , can you please edit the question with some sample values ...

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I edited the question please help

Comment: Those are output values, but what about the inputs ?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhani edited with input values too

Comment: What's the data type of them(date_column1/2) ? `date`? Btw, `to_date()` conversion needs a format model which are missing within the question.

Comment: [Yesterday you said](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73608827/266304) they were DATE columns; so why are you calling `to_date()` on them? That will implicitly convert to strings and back to dates, both using NLS settings, and is likely to cause issues. But the error suggests they are actually strings - if so you need to specify the format model to override NLS settings.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a oracle view in which we have column called `dayofset` which defined from subtraction of two date columns like `to_date(date_column1)-to_date(date_column2)` and it is stored as `number(38)` datatype.

Never use `TO_DATE` on a column that is already a `DATE` data type. Just use.

```sql
CREATE VIEW your_view (dayofset)
SELECT date_column1 - date_column2
FROM   your_table;
```

If you use `TO_DATE` then it takes a string as the first argument so you are effectively performing an implicit conversion to a string to convert it back to a date and your code is the equivalent of:

```sql
CREATE VIEW your_view (dayofset)
SELECT TO_DATE(
         TO_CHAR(
           date_column1,
           (SELECT value FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT')
         ),
         (SELECT value FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT')
       )
       -
       TO_DATE(
         TO_CHAR(
           date_column2,
           (SELECT value FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT')
         ),
         (SELECT value FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT')
       )
FROM   your_table;
```

Depending on your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter, this could just be a waste of time or it could truncate the date and give you an unexpected result; however, any user can change their session parameters at any time so you may get different results for different users so you should **NEVER** rely on implicit conversions.

---

If your columns are not a `DATE` data-type but are strings then use an explicit format model (and, if required, language) in the conversion:

```sql
CREATE VIEW your_view (dayofset)
SELECT TO_DATE(string_column1, 'DD-MON-RR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English')
       - TO_DATE(string_column2, 'DD-MON-RR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English')
FROM   your_table;
```

Comment: @MTO we have date like timestamp,if we subtract two timestamps we arebgetting like 1.3,2.4 like that,so we converted that into to_date()

Comment: @Intiyaz If you subtract two `TIMESTAMP` data-types then you will not get a number as the result, you would get an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND`. In Oracle, a `DATE` data type has both date and time components. If you want to get the full days difference then use `FLOOR(date_column1 - date_column2)` and if you want to find the difference ignoring the time component then use `TRUNC(date_column1) - TRUNC(date_column2)`; do **NOT** use `TO_DATE` to try to get rid of the time component of a `DATE` data-type.